# Preventing access to a directory for a specific group

Tags: permissions, file-permissions

I'm running a competition as part of a class on web application development. I need to prevent one user group from accessing the other user group's work directory and vice versa.

I know I'll be preventing web access using a .htaccess file, and I'm fine on that front. I need to prevent permission access on the command line so that one group can't access the other group's directory. Seems like a simple chown and chmod thing, but I'm getting stuck.

My impression is that it should be something like:

```
chown -R :250a 250_A
chmod -R 707 250_A
```

but that allows world access, so the group can get into the directory. I just want to prevent one group (250b) from getting into the group.

Comment: Although, it'd be good to tag which platform you're talking about so it's clearer from the list...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your operating environment you might have Access Control Lists available (ACL's).

On RedHat Linux you could do something like:

setfacl -R -m g:redgroup:--- dirname

ACL's can give you much more granularity about who can see what.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to simply change the permissions for the directory to 2770, and then add the account your web server runs under to the **250a** group.  That way you won't need to give permissions to *other*.

```
ls -al 250_A/
total 8
drwxrws---  2 250a 250a 4096 2009-09-21 12:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 93 root root 4096 2009-09-21 12:18 ..
```

/etc/group

```
250a:x:112:250a,www-data
```

Oh, just a little reminder.  After you add the web service account to the group you'll probably need to restart the web server.

Comment: "add the account your web server runs under to the 250a group"

And all the other groups.